# cannot convert argument 3 from 'const QGraphicsItem *' to 'const QObject *', which is this pointer, object is QGraphicsObject's subclass

Tags: c++, qt, pointers

my code:

```
//forkliftitem.h
class ForkliftItem : public QGraphicsObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    //some necessary code...
}

//forkliftitem.cpp
ForkliftItem::ForkliftItem()
{
    //some other code...
    connect(this, &ForkliftItem::faceChanged, this, &ForkliftItem::setRotation);
}
```

When I compile my code will generate the error as shown in title.Certainly,

> cannot convert argument 3 from 'const QGraphicsItem *' to 'const
>   QObject *'

because `QGraphicsItem *` is not inherited from `QObject`.**But** my `this` pointer's type is `const ForkliftItem *`, and `ForkliftItem` is inherited from `QGraphicsObject`.

And compile information have the following tips:

> see reference to function template instantiation
>   'QMetaObject::Connection QObject::connect<void(__thiscall
>   ForkliftItem::* )(int),void(__thiscall QGraphicsItem::*
>   )(qreal)>(const ForkliftItem *,Func1,const QGraphicsItem
>   *,Func2,Qt::ConnectionType)' being compiled with [
>       Func1=void (__thiscall ForkliftItem::* )(int)

can be seen : argument 3 of `connect()` is handled as `const QGraphicsItem *`, that why generate the compile error.

I could repair the error by following code:

```
connect(this, &ForkliftItem::faceChanged, this, 
    static_cast<void (ForkliftItem::*) (qreal)>(&ForkliftItem::setRotation));
```

But I feel very confused by that `const ForkliftItem *` became `const QGraphicsItem *` when call `connect(this, fun1, this, fun2)`, and argument 1 is used correctly and argument 3 not.Anybody knows, please tell me, thanks.

Comment: Besides, how to escape "<>" to show it other than HTML symbols here.

Comment: There is this guy here who says he has solved adding include QGraphisObject .. take a look https://forum.qt.io/topic/12491/solved-casting-qgraphicsobject-to-qobject-for-connecting-qml-signals-to-c-slots-harmattan-specific-issues/2

Comment: Please update your question to include a [MCVE].  As it stands there is a lot of relevant information missing.

Comment: What's the signature of `ForkliftItem::faceChanged`?

Comment: Note: you can also see this when you're calling into a derived class member function instead of the base class virtual member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I could repair the error by following code:
>
> ```
> connect(this, &ForkliftItem::faceChanged, this, 
>     static_cast<void (ForkliftItem::*) (qreal)>(&ForkliftItem::setRotation));
> ```

That's because `setRotation`'s signature is `QGraphicsItem::setRotation`, no matter what derived class you specify when taking the address, and `connect` enforces that the method you invoke is in a class derived from `QObject`.

The explicit cast is safe and a decent workaround that doesn't invoke undefined behavior. Another workaround would be to re-implement the method:

```
class ForkliftItem : public QGraphicsObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   Q_SIGNAL void faceChanged(qreal);
   void setRotation(qreal angle) { QGraphicsObject::setRotation(angle); }
   ForkliftItem() {
      connect(this, &ForkliftItem::faceChanged, this, &ForkliftItem::setRotation);
   }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that [setRotation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsitem.html#setRotation) is a member inherited from QGraphicItem, a class that doesn't inherit from QObject. [QGraphicsObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsobject.html) class inherits from 2 classes: QObject and QGraphicItem.

Either connect the signal to a lambda or create your own slot and call that method in there.

```
connect(this, &ForkliftItem::faceChanged, [this](qreal angle) { this->setRotation(angle); });
```

Comment: You mean `this ` match following function?I feel your explanation is not very clear.

Comment: @Crawl.W i don't understand your question. I meant that _this_ is casted in a QGraphicItem* because the function connected (setRotation) is a member inherited from QGraphicItem (ForkLiftItem inherits indirectly from QGraphicItem).

Comment: `connect(this, &ForkliftItem::faceChanged, [this](qreal angle) { this->setRotation(angle); });` will crash at run-time.Error msg:ASSERT:"unindexedItems.isEmpty()" in file qgraphicsscenebstreeindex.cpp, I get this msg when I handle gui-thread from non-gui thread before. And `connect(this, &ForkliftItem::faceChanged, this, [this](qreal angle) { this->setRotation(angle); });` goes well.